# How to prevent firestore document fields from updating

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to write a Firebase security rule for document update which achieves the following:

1. The user is the owner of the document
2. Enforces that only username, email, modified, and active are present in the request (i.e no extra fields)
3. Prevents the created date from being in the request and/or being overwritten/updated

Here are my security rules:

```
function isAuthenticated(){
    // Determine if the requesting user is authenticated
    return request.auth.uid != null;
}

function isUser(uid) {
    // Determine if the requesting user is the user
    return isAuthenticated() && request.auth.uid == uid;
}

function verifyFields(required, optional) {
    let allAllowedFields = required.concat(optional);
    return request.resource.data.keys().hasAll(required) &&
    request.resource.data.keys().hasOnly(allAllowedFields);
}

match /users/{uid} {
    allow read: if isUser(uid);
    allow create: if isUser(uid) && verifyFields(['username', 'email','created','modified','active'],['roles']);
    allow update: if isUser(uid) && request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys().hasOnly(['username','email','modified','active']);
    allow delete: if isUser(uid);
```

The create rule runs without issue, however the update rule fails because request.resource.data is a map with all the future document's keys, so it will contain all keys that were in the document on create, such as the created field.

Any ideas to enforce keys to be present but also enforce that a key cannot updated?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function isUnchanged(field) {
  return request.resource.data[field] == resource.data[field]
}

allow update: if isUnchanged('created') && // ...
```